# Does the app leave anything behind when you uninstall it?

Tags: applications, security, monterey

If I install an app from the App Store and then uninstall it, will it leave any changes other than the system log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most apps will leave behind things such as receipts, preference files, scripts etc.
These are generally harmless but take up small amounts of disk space.

Using something like [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/)(freeware) will let you see what bits may be left over & allow you to selectively delete them too.

Random example…

[image]

Comment: I used this app for years and I can't uninstall any app without using AppCleaner anymore !