# Can an application leave some files behind after it is uninstalled on iOS, and can it slow down or harm the OS in other ways after it is uninstalled?

Tags: ios, applications, performance

I wonder the following questions about uninstalling iOS applications:

1. Can an application leave some files behind after it is uninstalled?
2. Can an application slow down or harm the OS in other ways after it is uninstalled?
3. Will installing and uninstalling a large amount of applications cause any issue?

I found [Does the app leave anything behind when you uninstall it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/429835/20338) but that is for macOS. Android is [notorious](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/252974/12202) for allowing apps to leave some files behind after the uninstallation, so I wonder how iOS handles it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While **the entire app container is deleted on uninstall**, including the app's read-only files representing itself and its read-write files for user documents and settings, there are other things that can persist:

#### Documents

When uninstalling an app that uses iCloud documents, the confirmation prompt warns that iCloud documents will be kept. These can be removed separately by deleting the app's folder from iCloud in the Files app.

#### [Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services)

Any entries added to the keychain by the app are persisted.

> The keychain is not limited to passwords, […]. You can store other secrets that the user explicitly cares about, such as credit card information or even short notes. You can also store items that the user needs but may not be aware of.

The only way to remove these is to factory reset iOS and not restore from backup.

#### App Group container

An app can register itself as part of an app group and share a container with other apps in the group (by the same developer). If you have another app installed from the same group, the app group's container is kept. This will be removed once the last app from the app group is uninstalled.

#### [DeviceCheck](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck) bits

An app can set

> two per-device binary digits

which are kept persistently.